# Android WebView - after opening new window how to get back to previous?

Tags: android, webview

I have an Android WebView that opens a URL. That URL then opens a popup window via javascript. This works fine as I have the following set:

```
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
```

However, on the new window I have some javascript to close the window:

```
self.close()
```

However, nothing happens when that javascript is executed. Is there a way using javascript that I can close the window that has appeared in the webview and return to the window behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is supposed to listen to `WebChromeClient.onCloseWindow` and remove the WebView in your code. A WebView instance just can't destroy itself.